# Regex invalid on match

Tags: regex

I need regex to return invalid on a match. Specifically, the match is a string that starts with an A or an M and is followed by four numbers ie, A1223. The four numbers could be any random sequence.

I'm sure lookarounds are the way to handle this but I haven't grasped regex as a concept just yet. Thus far I've discovered how to capture the matched strings separate from other strings with the following.

```
([\s\S]*?)(A[\d][\d][\d][\d]|M[\d][\d][\d][\d])
```

Appreciate the help.

Comment: You need to provide some sample data, indicating which should and which should not be matched. It's unclear what exactly you mean by *return invalid on a match*. Do you want it to return false if there is a match and true if there is not? Or return true if there is a match and false if not? Are you trying to capture the part that consists of an A or M followed by 4 digits? Or capture the parts around it? Or something else entirely? Also, what regex flavor are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Regex doesn't really have match negation, but [you can (ab)use a negative lookahead assertion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/406408/712649) to do inverted matching:

```
^((?!\s[AM]\d{4}).){6}
```

Answer (score 0):

to match all strings not starting with A or M followed by 4 digits:

with [negative lookahead](https://regex101.com/r/iP9lE2/1):

```
^(?![AM]\d{4}).*
```

with [consuming pattern](https://regex101.com/r/iP9lE2/4) using `()` capture groups:

```
[AM]\d{4}.*|(.+)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Consuming pattern is a new concept for me. This works beautifully.